# New to jest - how would I write a test for this method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have this method below:

```
onViewed() {
  const { current } = this.state;
  this.slides[current] = { ...this.slides[current], viewed: true };

  const filtered = _.filter(this.slides,
    slide => slide.section === this.slides[current].section);

  if (filtered.every(slide => slide.viewed)) {
    this.onSectionComplete(this.slides[current].section);
  }
}
```

And I do not know Jest very well and wondered how you would unit test a method like this so that I can learn from it. I know that the expectation is whether the method 'onSectionComplete()' was fired or not but I don't know how would you set up to achieve this. I really appreciate your help.

Here is my test as is:

```
test('method onViewed()', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TutorialCarousel {...mockProps} />);
  wrapper.instance().onViewed();
  expect(wrapper.instance().onSectionComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: With any testing you should focus on testing from the outside. In this case you're trying to test an internal method calling another internal method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a spy on a method like this:

```
const onSectionComplete = jest.spyOn(TutorialCarousel.prototype, 'onSectionComplete');

const wrapper = shallow(<TutorialCarousel {...mockProps} />);
  wrapper.instance().onViewed();

expect(onSectionComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this - I think I understand it however the method `onSectionComplete` will not have been called because in the method there is an if statement, how would I work the test to get this to be called? Thanks again for your answer

Comment: Can’t you set the `wrapper.instance().slides` to the value you need for the if to pass before calling `wrapper.instance().onViewed()`?